# ejs: How to pass a variable contained by <% %> into the block contained by <script> tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to draw a rectangular on the client-side depending on the variable passed from express, but I don't know how to let this variable accessible by the `<script>` block.

```
<script> 
    var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 100);
</script>
<% var size = rows[0].size %>
```

How can I let the width of the rectangular be the variable "size"?

Comment: You probably want `var size = <% rows[0].size %>;` to use `size` variable in client from value printed on server

Comment: Yes. But I tried that and it seems that `<% %>`can not be used in `<script>`